# RecyclerView - Continuous Columns Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a layout where items would follow one another in columns (see image below) but I am not getting there yet. I have tried `GridLayoutManager` and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` - the problem with both neither provides the feature of item flowing into another column and following each other this way. With my current attempt I am trying `FlexboxLayoutManager` but the result I am getting is always columns with single items instead of the items flowing one after another.

The desired behavior is that the items are located one after another and when the high of the recycler doesn't allow for the full item view it should be broken down to the next column.

Here is what I am trying right now:

```
mBinding?.activeRecycler?.layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
            flexDirection = FlexDirection.COLUMN
            flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
            alignItems = AlignItems.STRETCH
        }
```

And this is getting me one item per column.

Trying to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`?

Comment: edited the question, StaggeredGridLayoutManager doesn't provide what I am looking for - specifically items flowing to the next column if the height is bigger

Comment: How is a LayoutManager supposed to break up an item in two like your graphic for item 3? It can only manipulate the existing items from a layout perspective.
Can you be more specific about what kind of content you are displaying and how it should look when it is split up in the middle like for item 3?

Comment: @ymindstorm I am displaying a card with multiple text fields, it should look like it reaches the bottom of window and continues on the next column as if it flows into the second column. Yes, I understand that layout manager can manipulate an item so I would like to manipulate an existing item to display on 2 columns if the height is bigger than window allows (as item 3).

Comment: Layout manager can be a custom solution, or any solution that will allow for the use of recycler view is welcome

Comment: @Rainmaker I will clarify my point: What ultimately happens, when the LayoutManager is done, is that your view receives a rectangle area on the screen to draw itself with a specific width and height. Additionally you can perform specific transformations on the resulting view. But there is no way to communicate to an item view "please, split yourself in half" from the LayoutManager.

Comment: What I would suggest is to try and make the individual view items very small so that one logical item consists of multiple building block RecyclerView items. This way you can use e.g. StaggeredGridViewManager with natural looking "breaks" in your items. To really help you out with code more specifics about your view content are necessary.

Comment: @ymindstorm actually it is a good point in a way, a have header, recycler with items and footer so I can split my item logically there in a way.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt this is possible.
The RecyclerView, its adapters and its layout managers all are not designed to alter the fundamental form of a view.

Meaning that "splitting" one would not be possible.
The RecyclerView is designed to understand how many views are in sight at the same time, create that many views only and then bind the underlying objects to the views respectively.

Meaning the RecyclerView doesn't "Cut a View in half and displays its halves in different places".

The only way in which a constellation like yours would be possible, was if the layout manager is specifically designed to display one item in multiple views and thereby multiple positions. Which would then allow it to be displayed as you described. However, as I said, that would mean the view `3` in the middle and the view `3` in the last column would be two views being bound to the same object or a copy of it. (Or someone went completely crazy and actually split the view, which I doubt).

I don't believe that any of the standard layout managers are capable of it and I doubt that you can even achieve this without also altering the adapter accordingly, at the very least. Because the adapter basically does the binding so without its help the standard layout managers wouldn't be able to do the double binding as described above.

That being said, this is just a very good guess, going by the principles of the view and its components. I have not read the source code or full description of every layout manager.

Comment: yeah, I was looking into splitting the view into 2 and binding with the same id to define it is the same object as it is not the matter of displaying but also processing the click events.

Comment: Exactly. So the split is basically impossible with the usual layout managers and even if you somehow manage to hack that behavior into them, i doubt that it would automatically mean you could process the views as you usually would.

Comment: but I can't even find the layout manager that would provide the vertical columns left to right flow at this point to split the views. It is as if no one ever tried to achieve this in Android

Comment: Correct, so you would have to build it yourself I guess. Either the layout manager and adapter or even a whole new view. Maybe a compound of multiple RecyclerViews. Anyway, this would probably be very difficult and exceed any reasonable SO answer

Comment: some answers do have quite a bit of code and answer pretty difficult problems especially In the bounty section. So I had hope :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your problem is like this: You have your current list of data that contains the text fields and you want to show them on the normal way, one list item one view item in recycler view.

But based on your design requirements this is not possible.

My idea to achieve that is like this:
You have to create a new list which will separate one item of the previous list into 2,3 or more items to fit in your columns.

```
private fun demo() {

    val originalList = listOf<String>()
    val newScreenSpecificList = mutableListOf<String>()

    val columnHeight = 3//example number of lines
    val columnWidth = 10//example number of chars
    var columnsIndex = 0//index of column
    var currentColumnHeight = 0 // current column filled height

    originalList.forEach {
        if (currentColumnHeight + getTextHeight(it, columnWidth) <= columnHeight) {
            newScreenSpecificList.add(it)
            currentColumnHeight = currentColumnHeight + getTextHeight(it, columnWidth)
        } else {
            //here is the part where your text is bigger then your column height so you need to divide it
            val textForSpaceLeft = getTextForSpaceLeft(it, columnHeight - currentColumnHeight)
            newScreenSpecificList.add(textForSpaceLeft)
            currentColumnHeight = currentColumnHeight + getTextHeight(textForSpaceLeft, columnWidth)

            if (currentColumnHeight >= columnHeight) {
                columnsIndex++
            }

            if (getTextForNewSpaceLeft(it, columnHeight - currentColumnHeight)){
                //continue to repeat logic for new column
                //...
            }

        }

        if (currentColumnHeight >= columnHeight) {
            columnsIndex++
        }
    }

}

private fun getTextForSpaceLeft(it: String, spaceLeft: Int): String {
    return "it"// return text for the available space
}

private fun getTextForNewSpaceLeft(it: String, spaceLeft: Int): String {
    return "new column also"// return text left for the new available space
}

private fun getTextHeight(text: String, columnWidth: Int): Int {
    return 2//todo your logic to convert text length to number of lines needed for a specific width of the column
}
```

Now you need to continue this logic it is not complete, I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it does look like everything is going to breaking up the item to several items and moving blocks to the new column when the height doesn't allow to fit it in, I understand this logic needs to be worked on more.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your problem is with the `LayoutParams` of items which are being created in your adapter. probably the height is set to `match_parent` in items. You can try to change the `LayoutParams` of itemViews in your adapter's `onCreateViewHolder`/`onBindViewHolder`. Or if the items' heights are kinda tricky to calculate, you can create a customView and try calculate the height in onMeasure and set the height to `wrap_content`

try to set items' height to `wrap_content` or if you want to do it in code, something like this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FlexItemViewHolder {
    val infatedView = ...
    
    infatedView.layoutParams = FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams(FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    infatedView.addView(textView)
    return FlexItemViewHolder(f)
}
```

Comment: How does this help with items flowing into the next column, when too long?

Comment: the height is wrap_content, the problem that with wrap_content it can be bigger than the whole screen height.